# multiple map in ionic apps (javascript sdk)

Tags: angular, dictionary, ionic-framework

I am using the google map (javascript sdk) in ionic V3 and I created 2 pages in ionic with map view. 
In the first page the map works well however once i open the second page the map appears with grey lines, no markers, street cuts in the middle ... 
does anyone experience this issue?
is it possible to have many maps in different pages in the same ionic application ??
many thanks for the help and recommandation

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've encountered that once, 
A way around it and to make your application performance better, is to create a service: `ionic g provider mapService`

And then create there general variables that gonna hold the map (so you'll have a singleton) then it will be centralized and not loading different map on, and you can store each specific thing (markers, clusters...etc)

Comment: thanks Sletheren
I tried to use mapservice provider but did not work for me.
Could you please share an example 
thanks